# How to properly identify this number using Tesseract?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have that image:

[image: Input]

And, I have that code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Users\\Никитос\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

img = Image.open('C:\\Users\\Никитос\\Desktop\\unknown.jpg')
enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
img = enhancer.enhance(2)

# Преобразуем в черно-белый рисунок:
thresh = 200
fn = lambda x : 255 if x > thresh else 0
res = img.convert('L').point(fn, mode='1')

res.save("res.jpg") #сохранил предварительно обработанный файл для наглядности
text = pytesseract.image_to_string("res.jpg",config='--psm 11 digits')
print(text)
```

The printed result is `45860`, but I want the correct result of `35860`. How to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

That image was unexpectedly tough. Here's what worked for me:

- Load image as grayscale.
- Crop to white area.
- Stretch image vertically, because the "font" kind of looks very bold.
- "Round" the edges, because the `3` mostly likely is mis-identified as `4` due to the "straight lines appearance" of the "font".
- Blur to further weaken that "straight line appearance".

The final looks like this:

[image: Output]

Also, I had to use [page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) `8`, i.e. *treat the image as a single word*, `11` or `6` (which mostly does the job) didn't work.

Here's the full code – I used OpenCV instead of Pillow for personal convenience:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

# Read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('2hkeg.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Crop to white area
img = cv2.threshold(img, 252, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(img)
img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# Stretch vertically
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), img, 1.0, 1.3)

# Round edges
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,
                       cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 11)))

# Blur
img = cv2.blur(img, (11, 11))

# Extract text
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 8 digits')
print(text.replace('\f', '').replace('\n', ''))
# 35860
```

There's no guarantee, that this approach will work for other even very similar images!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
Python:        3.9.6
PyCharm:       2021.2
OpenCV:        4.5.3
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Dropping random error messages isn't that helpful... Your `img` object obviously is `None`. Have you verified that the image was properly loaded, e.g. by debugging your code? Is the image path correct?